# Detect when LED is on

Tags: gpio, python, led

I'm trying to get the status of a LED (being controlled from another Pi, but on the same breadboard). If the LED is on, to get the other Pi (GPIO 25) status to be on and vice versa.

Here is the code for the detection:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

sensor1 = GPIO.input(25)

while True:
    if sensor1 == True:
        print("LED is on")
        sleep(0.1)
        
    else:
        print("LED is off!")
```

Here is a picture of the circuit:

[image]

The output I'm getting all the time is "off".

I have connected the GPIO 25 to the "+" of the LED, but I have tried the "-" as well.

What could I do to get that detection - when the LED is on and off?

---

Here is a sketch of the schematic. Hopefully it will help finding what the issue is.

[image]

Comment: Rather post a schematic instead of a picture.

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I prefer both, and a photo over a schematic.  A photo shows the actual connections.

Comment: @joan Ok, and I dislike to reconstruct the picture to a schematic. So I prefers a schematic and perhaps later a picture to prove that the connections is made correct.

Comment: That code will read GPIO **ONCE** then run around an infinite loop doing NOTHING!

Comment: @Milliways, how do I reset that status if that's the solution?

Comment: @yordan You could read the state inside the loop, but this would still be a poor solution. I would use something like https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_pressed but this is dependent on getting the hardware working first. Frankly it is difficult to even understand what you are trying to do or why.

Comment: @Milliways, I use this as a test setup for another project. There is a 5V LED indicator on it and when it has certain status, the LED lights on. That's what I would like to detect. It will be in a stand-by mode waiting for a signal from the LED if on and that's why I try to get the while loop working as well.

Comment: You need to read GPIO 25 in the loop.  At the moment you read it once and assign the value to sensor1.  Voting to close this general Python question.

Comment: @joan, I will try to work the GPIO25 in the loop. Thanks to everyone involved.

Comment: @yordan in future if you have further information to add to your question please use the edit button at the bottom of the question. Rather than posting new information as an answer. Since you are new here I recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com//tour).

Comment: It might be safer to detect the light from the LED than to connect to the wires. Connect a photo diode to GPIO25 with a suitable resistor and place it before the LED. That way you won't fry your RPi when the other project puts 12V on the diode or only 3V.

Answer (score 2):

If you are signalling a voltage level between two devices they need to have a common voltage reference.

Connect the grounds of the two Pis.

Comment: Should I reset state after in the while loop? If so, how do I reset it.

Comment: `a common voltage reference` is also called GROUND / GND.

Comment: This is only one half of the solution. The other answer shows how the state should be read _inside_ the loop.